# Usage of "request"

Tags: word-usage

Here is the sentence:

I requested all countries not to import gas and oil from X.

How to use the noun "request" instead of the verb "request" so the meaning of the sentence remains the same?

Maybe:

1. I made a request for all coutries to stop importing gas and oil from X.
2. I made a request for X's gas and oil to stop being imported by other countries.
3. I made a request for X's gas and oil not to be imported by other countries.

Answer (score 1):

Of your three options, the first is the best.

But you have changed the meaning slightly from **directly requesting those countries** to making a request **for them to do something**.

An improvement would be: **I made a request to all countries that they stop importing gas and oil from X.**

However, although this achieves your aim, it's a much wordier, less effective sentence than your original.

Comment: Can't I say "I made a request to all countries to do something"?

Comment: @Vova Yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest, most elegant form would be to use "request not to":

> I made a request to all other countries not to import gas and oil from X.

An example of this from the US government is: "if the consumer makes a specific request to that company not to call, the company may not call..." (["Q&A for Telemarketers & Sellers About DNC Provisions in TSR"](https://www.ftc.gov/business-guidance/resources/qa-telemarketers-sellers-about-dnc-provisions-tsr-0), US Federal Trade Commission))